# System.Net.DownloadFile()--where does the file download too with only a filename as the 2nd param in web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, download

Trying to setup a personal image upload/downloader webpage. I've viewed the msdn article on the function, and it runs fine but I cant figure out where it saves the file to.

```
var request = new WebClient();
request.DownloadFile("https://someabosolute/image/path/andfilename.png", "file.png");
```

Any Ideas?

@ escape or \ resolve an invalid character issue once you change filename.png to C:\tmp\filename.png. However using jsut a file name causes to errors everything runs but I cannot find the file. Even checked Windows security and application logs and there nothing relating to the time frame.

**SO where should the file be saved to in a web application when you only specify a filename as the second parameter in the DownloadFile() method of system.net.webclient.**

Comment: could someone test out the code from the MSDN docs in a MVC C# NET4.5 project. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the example in the [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe), the file will be downloaded to `Application.StartupPath`. If only a filename is provided, it will be saved in the same path as where your executable is.

Keep in mind that for some applications (e.g. ASP.NET web applications) there may be a permission issue saving the file in the same folder as the executable.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string remoteUri = "put your url here";
      string fileName = "image.php_.jpeg", myStringWebResource = null;
      // Create a new WebClient instance.
      WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
      // Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
      myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
      Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName, myStringWebResource);
      // Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
      myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, @"c:\tmp\" + fileName);
      Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, myStringWebResource);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm developing in VS 2012. I read that documentation and figured is would be the bin folder of the project. But alas no file, even when i do a full search on my filesystem.

Comment: The sample on the documentation is working, except that you need to find another image, as the image path from the sample is not existing. I tried the sample and it is saving the file in the bin\debug folder as expected. However if you use it in a ASP web application maybe your application does not have the rights to write the file. I think it is better always to provide a full path for where you want the file to be saved

Comment: Yes I was using my own image and I am implementing it into a web application. I have no debug folder in Bin only in views and how can I set credentials for IIS 8 express. I thought it just used the currently logged in user (an administrator)

Comment: Added C:\ to filename and it errors on ilegal characters. So i guess it only accepts only a filename.

Comment: Indeed on `C:\` I get a permission problem too.. but if I create a folder tmp and add `@"C:\tmp\"` to the DownloadFile it simply downloads the file to the 'C:\tmp' folder. If you implement it in a webapplication you need to find how the permissions for a folder should be that your webapplication can store data in there. I do not know what permissions are there, but I know that a web application has restricted access. I suggest that you create a test application (console app) to test the sample that I added to my answer. That should work. If it works, you can find out why your web app cant work

Comment: It was the escape sequence char "\" using the @ in the example above or using \\ resolve my problem.

Comment: I left the question open with a minor change if I dont get a specific answer ill close the question with you.

Answer (score 0):

...stupid me the default location with no path for the second parameter of is within C:\program files(x86)\iisexpress